# How can I change the color of the <nav> when I scroll on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll

> I already did it on desktop, but when I try the code with mobile, it crashes for some reason

```
    window.onscroll = () => {
  const nav = document.querySelector('#navbar');
 var viewportWidth = $(window).width();        
if (viewportWidth > 1020) {
        if(this.scrollY <= 500) nav.className = ''; else nav.className = 'scroll';}

};
```

Comment: What mobile platform? Are you sure that platform supports fat-arrow functions?

Comment: I think you might want to rethink your method to apply changes to the `nav` element. You are continuously editing the `class`Name when scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responsive design tends to be really hard to emulate using JS, so don't do more than necessary with JS:

```
window.onscroll = () => {
  const nav = document.querySelector('#navbar');
  nav.className = (this.scrollY <= 500) ? '' : 'scroll';
};
```

And use CSS media queries to have the color only be changed on mobile:

```
#navbar.scroll {
  /* when scrolling on desktop */
  background-color: green;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1019px) {
  #navbar.scroll {
    /* when scrolling on tablets or mobile */
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```